# How to access Child Component HTML Element values in Parent Component in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I have used below code to access child component HTML element values in parent component during parent component's button click.

**Child Component.ts:-**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `<md-input-container><label>Title</label><input [(ngModel)]="Title" #Title></md-input-container><md-input-container><label>Name</label><input [(ngModel)]="name" #Name></md-input-container><md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm><label>State</label><md-select [(ngModel)]="user.state" #State><md-option *ngFor="let state in states" value="{{state.abbrev}}">{{state.abbrev}}</md-option></md-select></md-input-container>`
})

export class ChildComponent {
  // some code here
}
```

**Parent Component.ts:-**

```
import {
    Directive,
    EventEmitter,
    Output,
    OnInit,
    ElementRef
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: `<child-component></child-component><button class="md-button md-ink-ripple" type="submit" (click)="SaveCustomerDetails()"><span class="ng-scope">Submit</span></button>`
})

export class ParentComponent {
   @ViewChild('Title') title:ElementRef;
   @ViewChild('State') state:ElementRef;
   Title: string;
   State: string;
   SaveCustomerDetails() {
     this.Title = this.title.nativeElement.value; // undefined
     this.State= this.state.nativeElement.innerHTML; // undefined
   }
}
```

**Plunker:-** https://plnkr.co/edit/r3237ta1XzhM2PX09pMl?p=preview

But I couldn't able get child component's HTML element values inside SaveCustomerDetails function. How to get entered values in parent component using ViewChild method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your components have a true parent/child relationship (one is nested within the other) then you can use the @Input and @Output decorators on properties to communicate between the two components.

I have a blog post about this here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/passing-data-to-and-raising-an-event-from-a-nested-component/

[image]

Here is an example of a child component with @Input and @Output decorators:

```
import { Component, OnChanges, Input, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'pm-star',
    templateUrl: './star.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./star.component.css']
})
export class StarComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() rating: number;
    starWidth: number;
    @Output() ratingClicked: EventEmitter<string> =
            new EventEmitter<string>();

    ngOnChanges(): void {
        this.starWidth = this.rating * 86 / 5;
    }

    onClick(): void {
        this.ratingClicked.emit(`The rating ${this.rating} was clicked!`);
    }
}
```

You can find the complete example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-GettingStarted

In any other scenario, you can build a service to communicate between your components, like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class ChildDataService {
  title: string;
  name: string;
}
```

See this plunker for more information: https://plnkr.co/edit/iODMVQzYwXcf5qJRR1El?p=preview

Comment: You have shared the click event example inside child component using EventEmitter. In my example click event is available inside parent component. I want to capture child component's HTML element values on parent component's button click. I have watched your pluralsight course also. If possible share the example in plunker with my requirement.

Comment: If you would like to build a plunker demonstrating your issue, I can take a look.

Comment: I have added my code in plunker tool. Have a look. https://plnkr.co/edit/r3237ta1XzhM2PX09pMl?p=preview.

Comment: Then I'd recommend a service. I updated your plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/iODMVQzYwXcf5qJRR1El?p=preview

Comment: @Maximus :-) I'll check out the publication. Thanks!

Comment: @DeborahK, Thank you for your response. The example you have given in plunker has been working fine.

Comment: @DeborahK, okay, cool) read [this](https://blog.angularindepth.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-follow-angular-in-depth-publication-6e37a7d7f988)

Comment: @DeborahK,  This service injection only the possible way or any other alternatives are there? If anything is available, kindly share me. What about ViewChild, ViewChildren and ContentChildren?

Answer (score 4):

Not that I'm advocating the use of @ViewChild here (it's a tightly-coupled solution), but if you want to do it without the use of @Output properties, it's possible:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `<input (change)='title=$event.target.value'>
             <input (change)='name=$event.target.value'>`
})

export class ChildComponent {
  title = "";
  name = "";
}

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  template: `<child-component #child></child-component><button type="submit" (click)="SaveCustomerDetails()">Submit</button>`,
})
export class ParentComponent {

  @ViewChild('child') myChild: ChildComponent;

  SaveCustomerDetails(){

    console.log(this.myChild.title + "" + this.myChild.name);
  }
}
}
```

I've modified your plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/mCGcIW1AVX2e9gEBzeC0?p=preview

Comment: Which one is best practice to implement i.e., Output or ViewChild. If possible, kindly share the code with Output properties because I am new to Angular2.

Comment: Using Output properties is better. In this video, I was explaining how to write loosely coupled components, and I use Output in one of them:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tSXx4NoKEYY

Comment: Thank you. I will look that video.